# AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.5

python 3.5.2

**code 1**

```
import urllib
s = urllib.parse.quote('"')
print(s)
```

it gave this error:

> AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'

**code 2**

```
from urllib.parse import quote  
# import urllib
# s = urllib.parse.quote('"')
s = quote('"')
print(s)
```

it works...

**code3**

```
from flask import Flask
# from urllib.parse import quote  
# s = quote('"')
import urllib
s = urllib.parse.quote('"')
print(s)
```

it works,too. because of flask?

Why I don't have the error anymore? is it a bug ?

Comment: You must `import urllib.parse`. I would assume that `Flask` also imports `urllib.parse`, and that's why your third example works.

Comment: For some reason this works in IPython just fine but fails in a Python script.  ```$ ipython
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 13 2018, 11:43:05)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: urllib.parse.quote('foo bar')
Out[2]: 'foo%20bar'```.  I'm unsure why it works there.

Answer (score 48):

The `urllib` package serves as a namespace only. There are other modules under `urllib` like `request` and `parse`.
For optimization importing `urllib` doesn't import other modules under it. Because doing so would consume processor cycles and memory, but people may not need those other modules.
Individual modules under `urllib` must be imported separately depending on the needs.

Try these, the first one fails but the second succeeds because when `flask` is imported `flask` itself imports `urllib.parse`.

```
python3 -c 'import urllib, sys;print(sys.modules["urllib.parse"])'
python3 -c 'import flask, sys;print(sys.modules["urllib.parse"])'
```

Comment: This was blowing my mind because I practice REPL driven development at the `bpython` REPL. There, importing `urllib` is enough to use `urllib.parse.unquote`. But in straight python3, thanks to this answer, I have discovered that I need to import `urllib.parse`. Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

For **code 1** to work you need to import the `urllib.parse` module, not the function `quote`. This way you can refer to the `quote` function with full module qualifier. With this approach you can use any function defined in the `parse` module:

```py
import urllib.parse
s = urllib.parse.quote('"')
print(s)
```

**code 2** works, because you import only the `parse` function and refer to it without module qualifier, since it is not imported in the context of the module. With this approach you can use only the explicitly imported function from the `parse` module.

**code 3** works, because `flask` imports implicitly the `urllib.parse` module. The `parse` module becomes available in the `urllib` module context. Once you import `urllib`, `urllib.parse` becomes readily available and you can use it as in **code 1**

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar issue and realized it's a version problem. So here is my solution in case it helps anyone:

```
# For Python 2.X
urllib.quote_plus(query)

# For Python 3.x
urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
```

Reference https://github.com/schollz/playlistfromsong/issues/36