# Script BLE does not yield results

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm completely new to Python. I need to use it in order to get my Adax-heater registered via BLE. This should provide me with a token with which I will be able to control my heater's temp via HTTP (local API)

Adax provided a page explaining what to do, including a python code. (I shall paste that code below)

---

I added the code to Pycharm, made a script out of it and then ran the script within Pycharm (from my pc, which is connected to my network via LAN). This yielded me only the following result:

```
C:\Users\*\PycharmProjects\Heater\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\*\PycharmProjects\Heater\.venv\Scripts\2Local.py 
C:\Users\*\PycharmProjects\Heater\.venv\Scripts\2Local.py:28: FutureWarning: The discover function will removed in a future version, use BleakScanner.discover instead.
  discovered = await bleak.discover(timeout = 60)
Press and hold OK button of the heater until the blue led starts blinking
```

---

Afterwards I tried running the script with CMD, there I got the following:

```
C:\Users\**\python 2local.py
Press and hold OK button of the heater until the blue led starts blinking
C:\Users\**\2local.py:28: FutureWarning: The discover function will removed in a future version, use BleakScanner.discover instead.
  discovered = await bleak.discover(timeout = 60)
```

---

From my very limited experience with Python, I reckon there's a problem with the code.

## What I did:

- made and ran a script as given by the company (see below)
- ran the script both in Pycharm as CMD

## What I should have recieved:

- a token with which I'll be able to authenticate myself via http using the local API

## Documentation page mentioned:

https://adax.no/wi-fi/api-development/#local

## Code entered

```py
# registers heater to your wifi network
# install dependencies with: pip install bleak requests

import bleak
import asyncio
import operator
import urllib
wifi_ssid    = 'MyWifiNetwork'  # replace with your wifi name
wifi_psk     = 'WifiNetworkPass'  # replace with your wifi psk
access_token = '12345678'     # generate some strong password for your heater

UUID_ADAX_BLE_SERVICE = '3885cc10-7c18-4ad4-a48d-bf11abf7cb92'
UUID_ADAX_BLE_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_COMMAND = '0000cc11-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

# ignore registered, non heater devices
def is_available_device(manufacturer_data):
    ADAX_DEVICE_TYPE_HEATER_BLE = 5
    if manufacturer_data and len(manufacturer_data) >= 10:
        type_id = manufacturer_data[0]
        status_byte = manufacturer_data[1]
        mac_id = 0
        for byte in manufacturer_data[2:10]:
            mac_id = mac_id * 256 + byte
        registered = status_byte & (0x1 << 0)
        managed = status_byte & (0x1 << 1)
        return mac_id and type_id == ADAX_DEVICE_TYPE_HEATER_BLE and not registered and not managed
    return False

# scan and return available heater
async def scan_for_any_available_ble_device():
    discovered = await bleak.discover(timeout = 60)
    if discovered:
        for discovered_item in discovered:
            metadata = discovered_item.metadata
            uuids = metadata['uuids'] if 'uuids' in metadata else None
            if uuids and UUID_ADAX_BLE_SERVICE in uuids:
                manufacturer_data_list = None
                manufacturer_data = metadata['manufacturer_data'] if 'manufacturer_data' in metadata else None
                if manufacturer_data:
                    first_bytes = next(iter(manufacturer_data))
                    if first_bytes:
                        other_bytes = manufacturer_data[first_bytes]
                        manufacturer_data_list = [first_bytes % 256, operator.floordiv(first_bytes, 256)] + list(other_bytes)
                if is_available_device(manufacturer_data_list):
                    return discovered_item.address
    return None

# handle notifications for heater
def command_notification_handler(uuid, data):
    BLE_COMMAND_STATUS_OK = 0
    BLE_COMMAND_STATUS_INVALID_WIFI = 1
    byte_list = None if not data else list(data)
    status = None if not byte_list else byte_list[0]
    if status == BLE_COMMAND_STATUS_OK:
        ip = None if not byte_list or len(byte_list) < 5 else '%d.%d.%d.%d' % (byte_list[1], byte_list[2], byte_list[3], byte_list[4])
        print('Heater Registered, use client_control_demo with IP: %s and token: %s' % (ip, access_token))
    elif status == BLE_COMMAND_STATUS_INVALID_WIFI:
        print('Invalid WiFi crendentials')

# send command to heater
async def write_command(command_byte_list, client):
    MAX_BYTES_IN_COMMAND_CHUNK = 17
    byte_count = len(command_byte_list)
    chunk_count = operator.floordiv(byte_count, MAX_BYTES_IN_COMMAND_CHUNK)
    if chunk_count * MAX_BYTES_IN_COMMAND_CHUNK < byte_count:
        chunk_count += 1
    sent_byte_count = 0
    chunk_nr = 0
    while chunk_nr < chunk_count:
        is_last = chunk_nr == (chunk_count - 1)
        chunk_data_length = byte_count - sent_byte_count if is_last else MAX_BYTES_IN_COMMAND_CHUNK
        chunk = [chunk_nr, 1 if is_last else 0] + command_byte_list[sent_byte_count:(sent_byte_count + chunk_data_length)]
        await client.write_gatt_char(UUID_ADAX_BLE_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_COMMAND, bytearray(chunk))
        sent_byte_count += chunk_data_length
        chunk_nr += 1

# register heater
async def register_devices(loop):
    print('Press and hold OK button of the heater until the blue led starts blinking')
    device = await scan_for_any_available_ble_device()
    if device:
        client = bleak.BleakClient(device, loop = loop)
        await client.connect()
        await client.start_notify(UUID_ADAX_BLE_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_COMMAND, command_notification_handler)
        ssid_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(wifi_ssid)
        psk_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(wifi_psk)
        access_token_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(access_token)
        byte_list = list(bytearray('command=join&ssid=' + ssid_encoded + '&psk=' + psk_encoded + '&token=' + access_token_encoded, 'ascii'))
        await write_command(byte_list, client)
#loop = asyncio.get_event_loop
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(register_devices(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

UPDATE ON NEW ERROR

```
C:\Users\de_pi>python 2local.py

Press and hold OK button of the heater until the blue led starts blinking

C:\Users\de_pi\2local.py:28: FutureWarning: The discover function will removed in a future version, use BleakScanner.discover instead.
  discovered = await bleak.discover(timeout = 60)

C:\Users\de_pi\2local.py:31: FutureWarning: BLEDevice.metadata is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Bleak, use AdvertisementData instead
  metadata = discovered_item.metadata
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<register_devices() done, defined at C:\Users\de_pi\2local.py:72> exception=AttributeError("module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\de_pi\2local.py", line 79, in register_devices
    ssid_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(wifi_ssid)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'
```

Comment: Is my assumption correct that the issue you are seeing is that the script isn't finding any devices? Before the line that has `if discovered:`, put `print(discovered)`. Do you see any BLE device listed? Do you see the device that you are trying to discover? Is the blue LED blinking?

Comment: Hey UkBax, indeed, the script does not show me anything to be honest. I tried your suggestion and got the following:



C:\Users\de_pi\PycharmProjects\Heater\.venv\Scripts\2Local.py:28: FutureWarning: The discover function will removed in a future version, use BleakScanner.discover instead.
  discovered = await bleak.discover(timeout = 60)
Press and hold OK button of the heater until the blue led starts blinking

Comment: You might want to try the debugging tips at: https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Thanks, I was able to progress a bit further now. I've updated the question with the new error that I receive.

Comment: You might want to replace `import urllib` with `import urllib.parse` at the top of the file. More information at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41502702/7721752. The shorter import worked for me in Pycharm but not on the command line.